# How to work with errors in swift 3?

Tags: swift, alert, nserror

I am using the following code:

```
   let jsonData1 = (try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "\(label2)")!)) as Data!
    var error : NSError?
    let ReadableJSON1 = JSON ( data:jsonData1!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil )


    if (error != nil){

        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert) //you can change message to whatever you want.
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }
```

If the app finds an error when opening the json file form the link, it should display an alert to the user. At the moment it is crashing and it seems that these actions are not executed and that is why I do not see the alert. Would you please help me how to fix that issue.
[image]

Comment: any reason you are not using `try` `catch`? mechanism?

Comment: Since Swift 2.2, (NS)Error are managed with try/catch: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html

Comment: What does the stack trace look like when you crash?

Comment: It simply stops working when I simulate it on my phone

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var json : [String: AnyObject]? // Property
do {
    let jsonData1 = (try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "\(label2)")!)) as Data!
    json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData1, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
} 
catch let error as NSError {
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert) //you can change message to whatever you want.
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return
}
```

Hope it will help! Happy Coding!

Comment: Where am I supposed to use that code, because I do not see how the json link is read here

Comment: well, you need to read the response data inside the do { } block. I have edited the answer. please check

Comment: let jsonData1 = (try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "\(label2)")!)) as Data!.. if this line of code return you Data? add some logs here and check what is the problem.

Comment: You are using some library to parse the JSON data. I have used JSONSerialization class provided by Apple. Thats why there are lot of errors. Can you let me know the name of the JSON library you are using in your project?

Comment: SwiftyJson is that you need ?

Comment: And ReadableJSON1 scope is local. Use it as a property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128294/discussion-between-dakata-and-iprogrammer).